# Maintain text colors when wrapping command in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, grep

So I've made a small script to search through my project for a word:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -n $1 js/*/**.js
grep -n $1 js/*.js
```

When running these commands in the command line I will get some nice syntax highlighting. But when I run them in a script I loose the colors. How can avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the trick, the `--color` flag takes care of coloured output. In your shell it is probably aliased.

```
#!/bin/bash
grep --color -n $1 js/*/**.js
grep --color -n $1 js/*.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Set these environment variables:

```
GREP_OPTIONS=--color=auto
GREP_COLOR=1;32
```

Where `1;32` is the color code for light green. You can change the color of highlighting using another code: http://hacktux.com/bash/colors.

Comment: Hmm, I modified this and set `export GREP_OPTIONS=--color` in the beginning of the script; which works. This may be preferable to Bernhard's solution for larger scripts.